# How to display an error message when a field is empty in a native script form?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nativescript, native

I'm trying to add an error message when the user leaves the email and password field empty, but it's not working, not sure where the problem is. I've tried to add some if statements in the script file so that the user cannot leave the field empty but I can't get the error message to display.

```
<template>
<Page>
    <ActionBar title="Register" />
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout id="register" class="registerform">
            <Label text="Email:" class="Email" />
            <TextField v-model="email" class="email"></TextField>
            <Label text="Password:" class="Password" />
            <TextField v-model="password" class="password"></TextField>

            </TextField>
            <Button text="Register" @tap="onRegisterTap" />
            {{userM}}
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   </Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "register",
    data() {
        return {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            userM: ""
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onRegisterTap: function() {
            this.userM = "";
            if (!this.email) {
                this.userM = "error: empty email";
                return;
            }
            if (!this.password) {
                this.userM = "error: empty password ";
                return;
            }
                else {
                this.userM =   " error: username or password is incorrect.";
                return;
            }



    };

</script>
```

Comment: You need to add `userM` in `data()`, otherwise Vue doesn't know that it should be reactive.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it's still not working.

Comment: You must add the attribute to data like Igor mentioned. Also You can not simply print userM out of no where. Unlike HTML, you always need a label at least to output text.

Comment: Like this: <Label text="{{userM}}" class="userM" />  ?   Because this isn't working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `<Label :text="userM" class="UserM" />` should work. Inline bindings are not supported (or at least warned against) in Vue. Here it is with your code: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=N7NbOk

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for the help. I'm not sure how to vote the answer, but it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Added an answer based on my comments and @Manoj's comments. You can mark that as the solution if it's working for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `userM` in `data()`, as otherwise Vue doesn't know that it should be reactive.

And you also need a Label to display the message in. In your case 
`<Label :text="userM" class="UserM" />` should work. Here it is working based on your code: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=N7NbOk

Answer (score 0):

You may use alert to view your error message to user:

```
onRegisterTap: function() {

            if (!this.email) {
                alert("error: empty email")
                return
            }
            if (!this.password) {
                alert("error: empty password ")
                return
            }
}
```